# LastInputInfo() in windows store apps

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I have been trying to monitor activity using GetLastInputInfo(). I am using a windows store app and I get many errors in the XamlTypeInfo.g.cs saying the LastInputInfo does not exist in the current context and the type of the MainPage is not valid in the given context.

I am new to windows store apps and I had no problems with this in wpf. Could you please help me?

This is what I use
 #region LastInput
        int totaltime = 0;

```
    // Declare a new instance of the structure LASTINPUTINFO contained in GetLastInputInfo 
    LASTINPUTINFO lastInputInf = new LASTINPUTINFO();

    // The following code calls the library user32.dll GetLastInputInfo and function. 
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool GetLastInputInfo(ref LASTINPUTINFO plii);

    // The DllImport attribute is very useful when reusing existing unmanaged code in a managed application. 
    // How can we find out within the term structure LASTINPUTINFO MarshalAs. 
    // Marshal is responsible to marshal data between managed and unmanaged code. 
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct LASTINPUTINFO
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        public int cbSize;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        public int dwTime;
    }

    public int GetLastInputTime()
    {
        int idletime = 0;

        lastInputInf.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(lastInputInf);
        lastInputInf.dwTime = 0;

        if (GetLastInputInfo(ref lastInputInf))
        {
            idletime = Environment.TickCount - lastInputInf.dwTime;
        }

        if (idletime != 0)
        {
            return idletime / 1000;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, object e)
    {
        totaltime = GetLastInputTime();
        if (totaltime > 10)
        {
            dt.Stop();
            TransitionScreenSaver();

        }

    }
```

Comment: This is completely inappropriate in a Store app.  It doesn't use windows anymore, you cannot use the user32 api.  You are not allowed to tinker with the screen saver.  Nor can you find out what's going on in the machine, your app is suspended and doesn't execute anymore when the user moves to another app.  Nor will code like this ever pass certification.  You will have to give up on this feature.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! what do you suggest I do? I need to determine the idle time in order to perform a transition to the screen saver?

Comment: Windows already has a screen saver.  It doesn't need your help.

Comment: yes but I am building a app for a kiosk and while the kisok is not in use after a time interval a personalized screen saver should be displayed.

Comment: Perhaps you should be writing a custom screensaver instead of trying to do it through your app...